# Excel - Reference a cell which references path of another workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

Is there a way to set a cell `A1` in `WORKBOOK1` to the filename of `WORKBOOK2`?

I am currently looking up the value I need in `WORKBOOK2` by hard coding the name of `WORKBOOK2` in the equation, **but the filename of `WORKBOOK2` is regularly changing**, which means I need to update the equation every time the filename of `WORKBOOK2` is changed.

I am using something a long the lines of:

```
=VLOOKUP(B1,'[WORKBOOK2]Data'!A1:B100,2,0)="8H",INDEX('[WORKBOOK2]Data'!E1:E100,MATCH(B1,'[WORKBOOK2]Data'!A1:A100,0))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can assemble a string for each of the range references, using "&" to concatenate the pieces. But then you have to use INDIRECT() to convert the strings back to an actual address.

If the name of your WORKBOOK2 is in A1, your formula would become:

`=VLOOKUP(B1,INDIRECT("'["&A1&"]Data'!A1:B100"),2,0)="8H",INDEX(INDIRECT("'["&A1&"]Data'!E1:E100",MATCH(B1,INDIRECT("'["&A1&"]Data'!A1:A100"),0))))`

Note: In my version of Excel, the filename extension is required, so the name in A1 would be "WORKBOOK2.xlsx".